# IF ELSE measures not returning 0

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

Good Day!
[image]

This is my code criteria, for the highlighted row, it will count ETD and ATD if there is value, but since there is none, it will return 0 and 0% for the calculation.

This is my measure,

```
CountNotBlank = 
SUMX(
ADDCOLUMNS(
RawDatas,
"Count",
var Direction = RawDatas[Direction]
var Dep = RawDatas[Dep]
var res1 = COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
 {RawDatas[ETD],RawDatas[ATD],RawDatas[ETA],RawDatas[ATA],RawDatas[Estimated Delivery],RawDatas[Actual Delivery]},
NOT ISBLANK([Value])))
var res2 = COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
 {RawDatas[ETA],RawDatas[ATA],RawDatas[Estimated Delivery],RawDatas[Actual Delivery]},
NOT ISBLANK([Value])) )
var res3 = COUNTROWS(
filter(
 {RawDatas[ETD] , RawDatas[ATD]},
NOT ISBLANK([Value]) ))
var res4 = COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
 {RawDatas[ETA],RawDatas[ATA]},
NOT ISBLANK([Value])))
return
if (Direction = "Export" && LEFT(Dep, 1) = "D", res2 , 
if (Direction = "Export" && NOT(LEFT(Dep, 1) = "D") , res1,
if (Direction = "Import" , res3,
if (Direction = "Domestic" , res4,
0))))),
[Count])
```

I tried returning 0 if a condition isn't met, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything I missed?
[image]

Expectation
[image]

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Attached with the pbix: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aHV6qz66yPMbqR34EdCEGd3UPK_lsStv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to produce your expected result by nesting the whole expression inside `IF(ISBLANK(...`:

```
CountNotBlank = 
VAR notblankvar = 
//your code from above not pasted here for readability//
RETURN IF(ISBLANK(notblankvar),0,notblankvar)
```

Let me know if it would be helpful to see my `.pbix` file.

Comment: Hi Alex, would you mind sharing your pbix?

Comment: Sure! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QG-aLXgKkJRHq4rBe0tgaKdpovFpCwnK/view?usp=sharing
If that works, please accept my answer as a solution. Thanks!